# Reading a text file and returning a array of dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to read a text file and return an array of dictionary in swift

the text file has the following data:

```
13582;Name 1;12345;5
13583;Name 2;23456;5
13585;Name 3;EX934;6
13598;Name 4;XE345_c;6
13600;Name 5;XF8765;6

 func machineNumberToName() -> [[String: String]] {
    var dic1 = [String: String]()
    var dic2 = [String: String]()
    var dic3 = [String: String]()
    var dic4 = [String: String]()
    // FileName for machines
    let fileName = "Machines.txt";
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil) {
        do {
            let contents = try! String(contentsOfFile: path)
            let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")
            for line in lines {
                var entries = lines.split(separator: ";")
                dic1["machineNumber"] = entries[0]
                dic2["machineName"] = entries[1]
                dic3["machineXML"] = entries[2]
                dic4["wifi"] = entries[3]
                return [dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4]
            }
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("file not found: \(fileName)")
        return []
    }
}
```

however I get the error

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Array<String.SubSequence>.SubSequence' (aka 'ArraySlice<Substring>') to subscript of type 'String'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Off topic but if this is your own file why not use json as the format and make use of Codable to decode this into an array of struct or a dictionary?

Comment: actually it's not my file, it would eventually be downloaded from a server with that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entries` is not an array of `String`, it is an array of `ArraySlice<Substring>`, or informally an array of substrings.

You can use `String(entries[0])` to get a string to put in your dictionary.

You have another problem though; You will only end up with the first line in the dictionaries, since you `return` out of the loop.   Even if you fix that, returning an array of dictionaries is icky. Create an appropriate struct and return an array of those structs

```
struct MachineDetails {
    let machineNumber: String
    let machineName: String
    let machineXML: String
    let machineWiFi: String
}

func getMachineDetails() -> [MachineDetails] {
    var details = [MachineDetails]()
    let fileName = "Machines.txt";
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil) {
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
            let lines = contents.split(separator: "\n")
            for line in lines {
                let entries = line.split(separator: ";").map { String($0) }
                if entries.count == 4 {
                    let newMachine = MachineDetails(machineNumber:entries[0],
                         machineName:entries[1],
                         machineXML:entries[2],
                         machineWiFi:entries[3])
                     details.append(newMachine)
                } else {
                    print("Malformed line \(line)")
                }
            }   
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("file not found: \(fileName)")
    }
    return details
}
```

Comment: You can also split by line break using `split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)`

Comment: thanks, however I'm getting the error No exact matches in call to initializer on line let entries = lines.split(separator: ";").map { String($0) }

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo it should be `line` not `lines`